# Django and WSGI and Apache2-- site is perfect in test server, won't load with Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, django, mod-wsgi

OK I don't what I'm doing wrong here. I have a Linode VPS running Ubuntu. I installed Django 1.3, Apache2, and mod-WSGI. I created my (extermely simple) website, slapped in some images, have a CSS sheet, have a favicon.ico and it works beautifully with the Django test server. The site looks precisely as it should -- all the images load, the CSS is working properly, etc.

Then I tried running the site with Apache and it won't work. Here are my relevant configuration files:

Apache sites-enabled/default:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin ***@***.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/django_site/django.wsgi
    AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.css) /srv/www/django_site/static_media/css/$1
    Alias /static_media/ /srv/www/django_site/static_media/

    <Directory /srv/www/django_site>
        Options -Indexes
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /srv/www/logs/error.log
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /srv/www/logs/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

My WSGI script (django.wsgi):

```
import os
import sys
path = '/srv/www'
if path not in sys.path:
   sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'django_site.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

When I try to surf to the website, I get a 500 internal error page. The traceback is this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
   response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

 File "/srv/www/django_site/quote/views.py", line 9, in about
   return render_to_response("pages/about.html", context_instance=RequestContext(request))

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py", line 20, in render_to_response
   return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 181, in render_to_string
   t = get_template(template_name)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 157, in get_template
   template, origin = find_template(template_name)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 128, in find_template
   loader = find_template_loader(loader_name)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 95, in find_template_loader
   mod = import_module(module)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in     import_module
   __import__(name)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loaders/app_directories.py", line 23, in <module>
   raise ImproperlyConfigured('ImportError %s: %s' % (app, e.args[0]))

ImproperlyConfigured: ImportError quote: No module named quote
```

In the traceback, I don't know why it is claiming that there is `No module named quote` since that module does indeed exist, and it works fine in the Django test server.

This should be straight forward. What boggles my mind is that I have a second Linode VPS running Ubuntu with a different website that has the exact configuration files and it works *perfectly*.

I bet this is some simple tweak and it will all work.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the 'quote' module or package located? Have you checked the permissions to ensure that user that Apache runs as can read it?

Comment: The "quote" module is simply an app within the `django_site` project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK -- I figured it out. After much hair pulling and frustration, it came down to a setting in my `settings.py` file. My original `settings.py` file had the installed app section with my little app `quote`. It looked like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'south',
'quote',
)
```

The app `South` is the MySQL schema migration utility and then we have my single app called `quote`. It was *this* line that was causing all the errors.

The solution: add my **project name** in front of my app's name. Like so:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'south',
'django_site.quote',
)
```

Yes. That is ***it***! Now the site works through Apache as it should. I don't understand why this wasn't causing similar errors on the Django test server. Oh well.

This screw up on my part is certainly humbling!

Answer (score 0):

Change `path` in your `django.wsgi` to `/srv/www/django_site`.

It's expecting to be able to import your modules into library code elsewhere, which it can't do without having them in the path.

Comment: Unfortunately this had the effect of causing WSGI to not know where the settings file is. As a result, the fun new error in the apache error log is `Could not import settings 'django_site.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named django_site.settings`. *pulling my hair out*

Comment: Do both, then.  `sys.path.append('/srv/www/django_site')`, `sys.path.append('/srv/www')`.

Comment: That doesn't change the situation.